# Get log of a range of revisions with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am executing

```
git log origin/<branch>..HEAD
```

in cmd and getting following information about commit yet not pushed to git.

> error: cannot spawn less: No such file or directory
>
> commit 436ab1eca3dfxxxxxxxxx569427f51badf2
>
> Author: Chawla,
>   Anukriti Date:   Fri May 11 13:38:37 2018> +0530
>
> Committed on : Fri May 11 13:38:37 IST 2018

I want its equivalent in JGit and tried the following but it didn't work:

```
for (RevCommit commit :git.log().add(git.getRepository().
  resolve("origin/<branch>..HEAD")).call()) {
  System.out.println(commit.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a branch was pushed or not does not affect the `LogCommand`. What you are looking for is probably `LogCommand::addRange` to obtain the log for a range of commits.

For example:

```java
ObjectId since = git.getRepository().resolve("refs/remotes/origin/some-branch");
ObjectId until = git.getRepository().resolve("HEAD");
for (RevCommit commit : git.log().addRange(since, until).call()) {
  // ...
}
```